# C# - IQueryable to ToList Async - EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, repository

I have a EF 6 project with a repository pattern approach.

```
private readonly DbContext _ctx = new SomeDbContext();

public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(bool noTracking = false)
{
    return !noTracking ? _ctx.Set<TEntity>() : _ctx.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
}
```

In my other project, that is business related and doesn't have any reference to EntityFramework.dll, it just access the repository project, I've made my own ToListAsync extension method.

It takes the IQueryable of T object returned from the repository and converts it asynchronously to a List of T.

```
public static async Task<IList<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    return await new Task<IList<T>>(query.ToList);
}
```

Usage:

```
await GetAll(true).Where(<some predicate>).ToListAsync();
```

The thing is, it just doesn't work. When the debbuger hit the extension method and tries to pass it, it just stops debugging, there's no error, no exception,  it just stops the application completely.

I've tried to change the how the Task is created, but no progress.

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

Altough I've changed the extension method and it apparently worked, a strange behavior is still there.

The extention methods only executes when I breakpoint it or don't call it async, if let it run freely, the debugger/application exits, it doesn't execute further code.

Works:

```
var x = repo.GetAll(true).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Doesn't works (the application just exits)

```
var x = await repo.GetAll(true).ToListAsync();
```

**UPDATE 2**:

All those tests were being held in a Console Application, so it's necessary to `wait` the async method, otherwise it will exit.

```
MethodX().Wait();
```

Comment: Why don't you use EF's async methods inside the repository?

Comment: I would have to change the return type of the repository methods from `IQueryable<T>` to `Task<IList<T>>`. In my business layer I want to have the flexibility to choose when to transform the query in a list and not always return a list. Sometimes I only need the IQueryable. But I don't know what takes more time: querying a database or materializing the results in a List.

Answer (score 1):

The Task you create is not started. You need to call Start() first.

Comment: I've changed that line to `return await Task.Run(() => query.ToList());`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've changed the extension method a bit.

```
return await Task.Run(() => query.ToList());
```

Apparently it's working now, but I'm almost sure that I've tried it...

Thanks anyway.

Comment: You really don't want to use `Task.Run` there. What benefit do you think this brings over `ToList`?

Comment: The materialization of the entities in the database (IQueryable -> ToList) could block the UI thread if not run `async`. It needs to be run in a separate thread. AFAIK it's a heavy operation.

Comment: In that case, I recommend that you either take the EF dependency and use true asynchronous methods, or expose the methods as synchronous and let the *calling* code use `Task.Run`. As it stands right now they're "fake asynchronous" - that is, methods with asynchronous signatures that just run synchronous code on a thread pool. I have a [short blog series](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) on the subject.